# Best way to call Gnosis Safe execTransaction from Vyper / web3.py?

Tags: web3.py, gnosis, safe, multisignature

I would like to interface the Gnosis safe execTransaction method in my contract (which is written in Vyper).

From what I've understood the execTransaction takes the following arguments (based on a Tenderly trace I did):

```
([Receiver] 0xf756f1fa0f01d225b5f7ed513f30e7feb2a900eb => GnosisSafeL2)
.
execTransaction
(to = 0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174, value = 0, data = 0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000577d74e7047966b5dec6f7af709295f0a1d1aacc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000a18f07d736b90be550000000, operation = 0, safeTxGas = 0, baseGas = 0, gasPrice = 0, gasToken = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, refundReceiver = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, signatures = 0x0000000000000000000000006076047ae211c46a284c8b3042819ed06b3148a1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)
=>
(true)
```

Where to is the contract being called and data is the calldata that will be passed through to the contract in the to field once the signature's check out. I understand this.

I have no problem generating the call data, however, the question becomes, how do I generate the signatures?

This particular safe has only 1 owner my wallet therefore, the question is, how do I generate the signatures for 1 owner using web3.py or 2 owners using web3.py and how do I successfully pass this to the execTransaction method.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you want to generate the txn data easily in python refer to [brownie-safe](https://github.com/banteg/brownie-safe)